# Proving $\lim (s_n - t_n) = s - t$ if $s_n \rightarrow s$ and $t_n \rightarrow t$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that $\lim (s_n - t_n) = s - t$ if $s_n \rightarrow s$ and $t_n \rightarrow t$. I'm guessing this is almost analogous to the case where $\lim (s_n + t_n)$, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making any mistakes in my proof.

> By convergence, we have that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \forall n > N_1$, $|s_n - s| < 2 \epsilon$.
>
> Similarly, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \forall n > N_2$, $|t_n - t| < \epsilon$.
>
> Let $ N = max \{N_1, N_2 \}$, and so $\forall n \geq N$:
>
> $|(s_n - t_n) - (s-t)| = | (s_n - s) - (t_n - t) | < 2 \epsilon - \epsilon = \epsilon$
>
> QED.

Comment: You need to use the triangle inequality before to $<2\epsilon-\epsilon$. We cant deduce that $|(s_n-s)-(t_n-t)|<2\epsilon-\epsilon$, or at least you need to explain this last step.

Comment: @Masacroso Ah I see. So the triangle inequality will give $|(s_n - t_n)-(s-t)| = |(s_n - s) - (t_n - t)| \leq |s_n - s| - |t_n - t| < 2 \epsilon - \epsilon = \epsilon$?

Comment: not exactly, more like $|(t_n-t)-(s_n-s)|\le|t_n-t|+|s_n-s|<2\epsilon$

Comment: @Masacroso Oh I see. My bad. Thanks! Then I would have to change $ 2 \epsilon - \epsilon$ to $\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ then?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively you can say that $2\epsilon=\gamma$ what is a quantity that have the same function as $\epsilon$, i.e., an arbitrary quantity bigger than zero.

Comment: Just show it for summation and the additive inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Since $s_n \to s$ and $t_n \to t$ we know that, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\displaystyle N_{1_\epsilon}, N_{2_\epsilon} \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \ge N_{1_\epsilon}$ $$|s_n-s|<\frac{\epsilon}{2},$$  and for all $n \ge N_{2_\epsilon}$ $$|t_n - t| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Now let $\displaystyle N = \max\{{N_{1_\epsilon},N_{2_\epsilon}}\}$, then for all $n \ge N$.\begin{align}|(s_n - t_n) - (s-t)| &= |(s_n-s)-(t_n-t)| \\
&\le |s_n -s| + |t_n - t| \\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.\end{align}

That is, $$(s_n - t_n) \to (s-t).$$